# ARIMA model with multivariate covariates?

Tags: time-series, arima, forecast

Lets start with my [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19jtltAojShckB4rDgTAJZaW0gpWjZSPh/view?usp=sharing) in which the first column, Y, is a time series observation along with 10 covariates, X1, X2, ..., X10. In fact, I have multivariate regressors and wanted to fit a times series model. I used this R-codes below:

```
dta = read.csv("D:\\...\\tdata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
y=dta[,1]
xt=data.matrix(dta[,2:11])  
fit = auto.arima(y, xreg = xt)
```

This generates ARIMA(0,0,0) model!! Look at the output:

```
Series: y 
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors 

Coefficients:
      intercept      X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6      X7      X8       X9      X10
        11.8458  0.0275  -0.0099  -0.0003  -0.0487  -0.0009  -0.0210  0.1427  0.0557  -0.0429  -0.0596
s.e.     0.9013  0.0149   0.0152   0.0038   0.0203   0.0038   0.0113  0.0092  0.0156   0.0113   0.0074

sigma^2 estimated as 0.565:  log likelihood=-65.37
AIC=154.73   AICc=160.97   BIC=180.45

Training set error measures:
                       ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE     MASE      ACF1
Training set 4.298502e-13 0.6829234 0.5405171 -0.1562922 3.199299 3.019104 0.1504265
```

I am afraid that I have made some mistakes!! Can any one be a kid of help!!!?

The second question is the forecast for the next 4 months. I used this R-code `forecast(fit, xreg =xt)`and this is the outcome. Would you please help me to validate this forecast?

[Forecast plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPcIN.png)

My third question is, how can I generate a similar plot if I use `arima`, instead of `auto.arima`?